# How to generate this list from user entered number using python?

Tags: python

```
I want to generate a list from user entered number using Python
I had tried it but I was unable to find out the proper solution for it.
```

> For example:
>
> If user enters 2, then list should be [1,1]
>
> If user enters 11, then list should be [1,2,3,4,1]
>
> If user enters 12, then list should be [1,2,3,4,2]
>
> If user enters 16, then list should be [1,2,3,4,5,1]
>
> If user enters 24 then list should be [1,2,3,4,5,6,3]

**Rules:**

1. Total of all the numbers in the list should equal the input number.
2. The first number in the list be 1
3. Except the last number, difference between any two elements should be 1
4. Last number should be equal to input number - sum of all the numbers in the list.

Comment: Whats the logic behind lists returned?

Comment: is this some kind of a...magic pattern?

Comment: Fit an AP with common difference 1 and when next value doesnt fit, include the remaining number.

Comment: I think the logic is: sum of all items is equal to that number.

Comment: People, I included the logic. Please stop downvoting. It looks like a valid and interesting question.

Comment: @thefourtheye No effort shown. Deserves all the downvotes it has

Comment: @Haidro Oops. I missed that. I thought that people were downvoting because he didnt explain the problem properly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP don't want to make any effort to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
maxNum, current, result = 12, 1, []

while maxNum > current:
    result.append(current)
    maxNum -= current
    current += 1
result.append(maxNum)
print result
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
```

**Edit:**

**Mathematical solution:**

```
inputNumber = int(raw_input("Please enter the input number: "))
a, b, c = 1, 1, -2 * inputNumber
innerPart = ((b**2) - 4 * a * c)**0.5
N = int(max((-b + innerPart) / (2 * a), (-b - innerPart) / (2 * a)))
result, sumTillN = [i for i in range(1, N + 1)], (N * (N + 1)) // 2
if inputNumber - sumTillN: result.append(inputNumber - sumTillN)
print result
```

First N - 1 elemets can be calculated using N(N+1)/2 formula. We can find positive N for `N^2+N-2*inputNumber` and fill the first N - 1 elements. The last element will be just the remainder.

Comment: @user2083375 Do you mind explaining what is wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong in it. Your code is correct..

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. I was trying for it for a long time.

Comment: Accepted your answer.